# Password storage with SHA-256 hash and AES using Bouncy Castle in Java

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I am new to password storage and to Bouncy Castle.

- Encryption : Is there a reason to prefer Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator
  over AES to encrypt(salt+hash(password+salt)) ?
- An example : [How to encrypt and salt the password using BouncyCastle API in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565369/how-to-encrypt-and-salt-the-password-using-bouncycastle-api-in-java)
- My Java code : is there a better way to get back the salt from the cipher than byte array extraction ?

Here is my java code :

```
// salt
java.security.SecureRandom rgen = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = rgen.generateSeed(20);
// add Bouncy Castle
java.security.Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
// aes secret key
javax.crypto.KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "BC");
Key cleSecrete = kgen.generateKey();
// aes
javax.crypto.Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES", "BC");
// sha-256
java.security.MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256","BC");

// hash the clear password with the salt to avoid collisions
byte[] motDePasseHash = hasherSaler(motDePasseClair.getBytes("UTF-8"),salt);
// Encrypt the hash with the salt to get the salt back
byte[] chiffreBDD = chiffrerSalerHash(salt,motDePasseHash,cleSecrete );
// Store the cipher in DB
...

// Get back the hash and the salt from DB
byte[] deChiffreBDD = deChiffrer(chiffreBDD,cleSecrete );
byte[] saltBDD = extraireOctets(deChiffreBDD,0,19);
byte[] hashBDD = extraireOctets(deChiffreBDD,20,deChiffreBDD.length-1);
// hash the user intput
byte[] motDePasseHashCandidat = hasherSaler(motDePasseClairCandidat.getBytes("UTF-8"),saltBDD);
// Compare hased user input with DB hash 
boolean isMotDePasseOK = Arrays.equals(hashBDD,motDePasseHashCandidat);

private final byte[] hasherSaler(byte[] clair,byte[] salt) {
    byte[] concat = concatenerOctets(clair,salt);
    return sha256.digest(concat);
}
private final byte[] chiffrerSalerHash(byte[] salt,byte[] hash, Key cle) {
    cipher.init(true,cle);
    return cipher.doFinal(concatenerOctets(salt,hash));
}
private final byte[] deChiffrer(byte[] chiffre, Key cle) {
    cipher.init(false,cle);
    return cipher.doFinal(chiffre);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this code even run? I don't see any `Cipher.init()` calls. Or is this a prototype?

Comment: It does not run, it is on my text editor for the moment. I want to collect the necessary steps first.

Comment: You say that my aes cipher has no initilization vector ? thanks a lot !

Comment: The fact that it has no key is a bigger problem, but yes, ciphers should have IV's too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504280/encryption-with-aes-256-and-the-initialization-vector

Comment: So IV is optional if I have a salt. But of course I need a secret key.

Comment: Code updated with a secret key

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to verify a password, you should only use PBKDF2 (or bcrypt/scrypt). A cipher should not be necessary. The salt can be stored without encryption. You may want to use an additional secret to append to the salt that you keep stored in e.g. the source code. Don't forget to store a protocol number with your passwords or you cannot upgrade later on.

As for your code, you should not use `generateSeed` for salts. You should use `update` more. `"AES"` uses ECB mode by default, so specify another mode. Don't rely on defaults. Use a (possibly derived) IV. Don't explicitly use a provider when not necessary.

OK, I could go on for quite a while, but this will have to do for now.