# AES-GCM-256 encryption

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, aes-gcm

We need to encrypt a UUID string using AES-GCM-256 and consumer will decrypt it using the same AES-GCM-256.As per the recommendation [(RFC)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4106) the IV(initialization vector) must be unique for each invocation,I am confused how IV values will be common or shared between encrypter and decrypter.

Comment: How will you transmit the data? An IV does not need to be secret, just unique per invocation. There is [some discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504280/encryption-with-aes-256-and-the-initialization-vector?rq=1)

Comment: but on the decrypter side,how he will know what is the value of IV,it should be same??

Comment: I would prepend the IV (it is a fixed number of bytes) to the transmission. On the receiving side, strip off the first *N* bytes, use that as the IV, and then decrypt.